# Nhibernate + QueryOver: filter with Where ignoring sensitive

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I am trying to build a simple query in nHibernate with QueryOver but I want it to convert everything lower-case or ignore sensitive:

```
Domain.User User = Session.QueryOver<Domain.User>()
       .Where(x=>x.Login=="username")
       .SingleOrDefault();
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**:

Someone suggested that the problem could be with the colletion of the DB but I've never had any kind of problem with that and this script works:

```
Domain.User User = Session
    .CreateCriteria<Domain.User>() 
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Login", "username")) 
    .UniqueResult<Domain.User>();
```

Comment: What is your database server and default database collation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In QueryOver you can use following:

```
Domain.User User = Session.QueryOver<Domain.User>()
       .WhereRestrictionOn(x=>x.Login).IsInsensitiveLike("username")
       .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: how could you explain the fact that the CreateCriteria works properly?

Comment: By default SQL server makes case insensitive strings comparison, but can be configured differently. ICriteria doesn't add anything in SQL it will just generate where Login = 'username'. Can't say it about QueryOver. You should check what SQL it produces. Insensitive like will cause ToLower call in SQL

Comment: I just ran into a problem with solution.  In this case, the username had an underscore character in it, and Oracle treats the underscore as a wildcard.  So I had both `bob.marley` and `bob_marley` in the database and the `SingleOrDefault` crashed.

Comment: Careful - allowing user input to be a LIKE expression is very prone to being a big security hole. NB, the OP did *not* ask for a Like, but for equality (which would make sense)

Comment: You should probably read question carefully before putting "valuable" comments

Comment: This logic is not the same as the question requires. Be careful with that "like".

Answer (score 6):

my workaround for this is using a expression.eq combined with a projection, so a case insensitive equals without any magic strings can be done with queryover

```
query.Where(Expression.Eq(Projections.Property(Of MyType)
                (Function(x) x.Name), "something").IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: The exact syntax above didn't work. Here is what worked for me:
 ```query.Where(Restrictions.Eq(nameof(MyClass.Property), value).IgnoreCase());```

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to change collation of your database to case insensitive one. If you can change database.

Comment: Darius, I don't know if it is a problem with the collection cause CreateCriteria works properly:Domain.User User = Session.CreateCriteria<Domain.User>() .Add(Expression.Eq("Login", "username")) .UniqueResult<Domain.User>();

Comment: @LeftyX - If your collation is case insensitive you don't have to specify case sensitivity in your query (all queries will be case insensitive by default).

Comment: You're right Darius but changing collation in Oracle is not as easy as in Sql Server and I can't do it cause I am not the owner of the DB.

Comment: np ;) - as I wrote 'If you can change database...'

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class QueryOverExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used in cases where the root type is required
    /// Example: .WhereEqualInsensitive(t => t.Property, stringValue)
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryOver<T, TU> WhereEqualInsensitive<T, TU>(this IQueryOver<T, TU> queryOver, Expression<Func<T, object>> path, string value)
    {
        return queryOver.Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.SqlFunction("upper", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property(path)), value.ToUpper()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used in cases where the root type is NOT required
    /// Example: .WhereEqualInsensitive(() => addressAlias.DefaultEmail, contactEmailAddress)
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryOver<T, TU> WhereEqualInsensitive<T,TU>(this IQueryOver<T, TU> queryOver, Expression<Func<object>> path, string value)
    {
        return queryOver.Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.SqlFunction("upper", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property(path)), value.ToUpper()));
    }
}
```

Usages:

```
Session.QueryOver<DTO>()
           .WhereEqualInsensitive(t => t.Property, value)

ChildDTO childAlias = null;
Session.QueryOver<DTO>()
           .JoinAlias(t => t.ChildDTO, () => childAlias)
           .WhereEqualInsensitive(() => myAlias.Property, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

NH 3.0 has a linq provider so you can use

```
Session.Query<Domain.User>()
           .Where(x=>x.Login.ToLower() =="username")
           .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I've already tried that. It doesn't work. I get this error: {"Unrecognised method call in epression x.Login.ToLower()"} . could it be cause I am using oracle?

Comment: @LeftyX what version nhibernate you have?

Comment: I've checked and the behavior is the same in Sql Server 2008: Unrecognised method call in epression x.Login.ToLower()

Comment: @LeftyX Confirm not working with QueryOver but working with linq to nhibernate. All i can to recomend you its use linq for nhibernate. its all ok with linq in version 3.0

Comment: It's strange cause if I create a critiria is case insensitive (and works): Domain.User User = Session.CreateCriteria<Domain.User>()
                        .Add(Expression.Eq("Login", "username"))
                        .UniqueResult<Domain.User>();