# NHibernate Query over case insensitive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using `QueryOver` and `islike` to get records from oracle db, but I want case insensitive

```
orgs = session.QueryOver<V_CM_ORG_GET>()
   .SelectList(list => list
       .SelectGroup(c => c.ORG_ID).WithAlias(()=>or.ORG_ID)
   .SelectGroup(c => c.ORG_NAME).WithAlias(() => or.ORG_NAME)
   .SelectGroup(c => c.PHONE).WithAlias(() => or.PHONE))
   .Where(Restrictions.On<V_CM_ORG_GET>(y=>y.ORG_NAME)
       .IsLike(query,MatchMode.Anywhere))
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<OrgsObj>())
   .List<OrgsObj>();
```

Answer (score 9):

Not fully sure if you really tried to search:

- [Nhibernate + QueryOver: filter with Where ignoring sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5244561/1679310)

As stated there, solution would be like this:

```
// instead of this
.Where(Restrictions.On<V_CM_ORG_GET>(y=>y.ORG_NAME)
    .IsLike(query,MatchMode.Anywhere))
// use this
.WhereRestrictionOn(y => y.ORG_NAME)
    .IsInsensitiveLike(query, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

Comment: Great if that works for you ;) Enjoy NHibernate, amazing tool